# Pivot data to gridview

Tags: php, mysql, yii, cgridview

I looked around for some time now and can't find an answer that fits my issue.

How can I pivot this table (see sample file) to show in Cgridview?

```
id_assistente(INT)|id_data(date)|id_horario(INT)|
|1                |2017-01-01   |1              |
|1                |2017-01-02   |2              |
|1                |2017-01-03   |3              |
|1                |2017-01-04   |3              |
|...              |...          |...            |
|2                |2017-01-01   |1              |
|2                |2017-01-02   |2              |
|2                |2017-01-03   |3              |
|2                |2017-01-04   |3              |
|...              |...          |...            |

I need it do display as:
id_assistente(INT)|2017-01-01|2017-01-02|2017-01-03|2017-01-04|...
1                 |1         |2         |3         |3         |...
2                 |1         |2         |3         |3         |...
```

[Sample DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoZkJ.jpg)

Comment: You should handle this in your application code. SQL is not suitable for this kind of manipulation.

Comment: My problem is, I can pivot it in php but the only way i learn'd / seen is knowing the "headers", and i need it to be dynamic, because I can search between 2 dates in several years...